# How to generate a lag variable (endogenous lag) that captures previous values?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data.table

I want generate the following  endogenous lag (Y) variable

```
set Y=1 in the current routine year, if submission==1 and routineyear==1 in the previous routine year

set Y=2 in the current routine year, if sub==0 and routineyear==1 in the previous routine year

Otherwise=0
```

Note though that "previous routine year" is not previous year, the intervals between routine years varies. This is actually what makes it hard for me to generate this variable.

Basically, I want to generate an endogenous variable that would capture state's behavior in their LAST `routineyear`.

To illustrate what I want to do:

Assume that country A had its routine year in **1990** - the same year the `submission` variable was also `=1`. This would generate `Y=1`.

Now, the next `routineyear` for country A is in **1992**, where the `submission=1` and `routineyear=1` in that year. The endogenous lag in this should indicate A's previous behavior as in **1990** (`Y=1`).

Then, the next `routineyear` is in **1996** where `submission=0` while `routineyear=1`. The endogenous lag in this case would be the value of A's previous behavior in **1992** (`Y=1`).

Then again,  next `routineyear` is in **1998**, `where submission=1` and `routineyear=1`. The endogenous lag here should indicate A's previous behavior in the last `routineyear`, in **1996**. that is: `Y=2`!.

This is how the endogenous lag should look like (based on the example above)

```
country year     submission routineyear  Y(endo lag)
A       1990          1            1     1  
A       1991          0            0     0
A       1992          1            1     1 
A       1993          1            0     0
A       1994          0            0     0
A       1995          0            0     0
A       1996          0            1     1
A       1997          0            0     0
A       1998          1            1     2
A       1999          0            0     0
A       2000          0            0     0
A       2001          0            1     1
A       2002          0            0     0
A       2003          1            1     2
```

I've been trying to do this using different logics but without success. One of the biggest problems is that routine year is different for each country, the intervals are not stable.

I believe that someone who can write proper codes/functions in R would be able to slove this puzzle. If not, I would appreciate all recommendations as how to proceed from here.

A sample from my real data:

> structure(list(ccode = c(31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L,  31L,
>   31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L,  31L, 40L,
>   40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L,  40L, 40L, 40L,
>   40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 41L,  41L, 41L, 41L, 41L,
>   41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L,  41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L,
>   41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L,  42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L,
>   42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L,  42L, 42L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L,
>   51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L,  51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L,
>   51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L,  52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L,
>   52L, 52L, 52L, 52L,  52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 53L,
>   53L, 53L, 53L,  53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 53L,
>   53L, 53L,  53L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L,
>   54L,  54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L,
>   70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L,  70L,
>   70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L,  80L, 80L,
>   80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L,  80L, 80L, 80L,
>   80L, 80L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L,  90L, 90L, 90L, 90L,
>   90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L,  90L), year = c(1990L,
>   1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L,  1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L,
>   2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L,  2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L,
>   2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L,  1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L,
>   1999L, 2000L, 2001L,  2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L,
>   2009L, 2010L,  2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L,
>   1997L,  1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L,
>   2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L,  1994L,
>   1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L,  2003L, 2004L,
>   2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L,  1990L, 1991L, 1992L,
>   1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L,  1999L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L,
>   2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L,  2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L,
>   1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L,  1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L,
>   2000L, 2001L, 2002L,  2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L,
>   2010L, 2011L,  1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L,
>   1998L,  1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L,
>   2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L,  1995L,
>   1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L,  2004L, 2005L,
>   2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L,  1991L, 1992L, 1993L,
>   1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L,  2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L,
>   2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L,  2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 1990L, 1991L,
>   1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L,  1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L,
>   2002L, 2003L, 2004L,  2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L,
>   1990L, 1991L,  1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L,
>   2000L,  2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L,
>   2010L, 2011L), country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L,
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  4L, 4L, 4L,
>   4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,  4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
>   4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,  8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,
>   8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,  6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,
>   6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,  6L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
>   9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,  9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L,
>   9L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,  11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,
>   11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L,  11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L,
>   5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,
>   5L, 5L, 5L,  5L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L,
>   10L, 10L,  10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 3L,
>   3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,  7L,
>   7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Bahamas", "Barbados", 
>   "Belize", "Cuba", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Guatemala", 
>   "Haiti", "Jamaica", "Mexico", "Trinidad and Tobago"), class =
>   "factor"), 
>       submission = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), routineyear = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>       0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
>       )), .Names = c("ccode", "year", "country", "submission",  "routineyear"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -243L ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)

DF[, Y := 0
   ][routineyear == 1
     , Y := 1 + (shift(submission, fill = 1) == 0)
     , by = country][]
```

which gives (first 15 rows shown):

> ```
> > DF
>     ccode year country submission routineyear Y
>  1:    31 1990 Bahamas          1           1 1
>  2:    31 1991 Bahamas          0           0 0
>  3:    31 1992 Bahamas          0           0 0
>  4:    31 1993 Bahamas          0           1 1
>  5:    31 1994 Bahamas          0           0 0
>  6:    31 1995 Bahamas          1           0 0
>  7:    31 1996 Bahamas          0           0 0
>  8:    31 1997 Bahamas          1           1 2
>  9:    31 1998 Bahamas          0           0 0
> 10:    31 1999 Bahamas          1           1 1
> 11:    31 2000 Bahamas          0           0 0
> 12:    31 2001 Bahamas          1           1 1
> 13:    31 2002 Bahamas          0           0 0
> 14:    31 2003 Bahamas          1           1 1
> 15:    31 2004 Bahamas          0           0 0
> ........
> ```

What this does:

- `setDT(DF)` converts your dataframe to a data.table
- `Y := 0` sets `Y` to `0` by reference first
- Filter for `routineyear == 1`
- Update `Y` by reference such that `Y` is set to `1` if previous submission is `1` and to `2` is previous submission is `0`

Comment: Thanks. This looks very clean. I'm trying this on my data now. One question though: I don't get how the "2"s are generated.

Comment: @Goulou The part `shift(submission, fill = 1) == 0` gives a `TRUE`/`FALSE` variable with `TRUE` for when the previous submission is equal to zero. And `1 + TRUE` gives `2`.

Comment: Thank you for this very elegant code, that I'm sure I can use in other contexts. It worked well!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

select(dat2, -Y) %>% 
  filter(routineyear == 1L) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(Y = 2L - lag(submission, default = 1L)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  right_join(select(dat2, -Y)) %>% 
  mutate(Y = replace(Y, is.na(Y), 0L))

# # A tibble: 14 x 5
#    country  year submission routineyear     Y
#    <fct>   <int>      <int>       <int> <int>
#  1 A        1990          1           1     1
#  2 A        1991          0           0     0
#  3 A        1992          1           1     1
#  4 A        1993          1           0     0
#  5 A        1994          0           0     0
#  6 A        1995          0           0     0
#  7 A        1996          0           1     1
#  8 A        1997          0           0     0
#  9 A        1998          1           1     2
# 10 A        1999          0           0     0
# 11 A        2000          0           0     0
# 12 A        2001          0           1     1
# 13 A        2002          0           0     0
# 14 A        2003          1           1     2

all.equal(.Last.value, dat2)
# [1] TRUE
```

where `dat2` is:

```
dat2 <- read.table(text = 
"country year     submission routineyear  Y
A       1990          1            1     1  
A       1991          0            0     0
A       1992          1            1     1 
A       1993          1            0     0
A       1994          0            0     0
A       1995          0            0     0
A       1996          0            1     1
A       1997          0            0     0
A       1998          1            1     2
A       1999          0            0     0
A       2000          0            0     0
A       2001          0            1     1
A       2002          0            0     0
A       2003          1            1     2
", header = TRUE)
```